# Foundation 5 CSS Z-index Top Bar dropdown menu issue

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, z-index

[image: hidden dropdown]

Hi all, 
I needed to add z-index:2 to the header elements, now the topbar nav drop down is appearing under. 
I tried to add {position:relative;z-index:999} on many elements, but it doesn't work. Any hints?

I am using CSS, margin is added to show the problem

Code here:
    [HTML and CSS][2]

```
[2]: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYKamg
```

Comment: .Please post your css and markup.

Comment: I am using foundation basic CSS. I just added position:relative;z-index:2 to  the containers. I will post the code

Comment: The position is the important part as z-index is only applied to elements that are positioned.

Comment: yes, that is why i am using "position:relative". But I think I am applying it tot the wrong element, or being overridden by foundation CSS !important rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this: `<div class="row show-for-medium-up" style="position:relative;z-index:2">`

To this:

`<div class="row show-for-medium-up" style="position:relative;z-index:3">`

The `z-index:` of `2` on this div is placing it in front of the navigation dropdown. So I think you need to move the container element of the dropdown nav up a level.

Comment: I know this of course, as I mentioned before, I need to add "z-index:2" to the header elements to use z-index:1 in the background for other elements. I want to push the drop down forward z-index:999 or so

Comment: Try reading through this: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/ 
Also inspect the element in Firefox and turn on the 3D view so that you can see how your elements are stacking. I would say you may have to apply `position: relative` and a `z-index` to a few more elements.

Comment: Yes I know it's z-index and i was trying to go through the correct element but I couldn't. I posted the right answer i finally got. The parent container must be edited itself.

Comment: Yeah, sorry @Yasser I misread your original question and have now updated my answer, although I see you have also now found the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row show-for-medium-up" style="position:relative;z-index:99">
```

This fixed it, Setting the parent container to a higher z-index. I am pretty sure I tried this more than once yesterday. Thanks guys. I will keep you posted if anything pops up.